# Why does get_posts() return only 5 matching posts, when it should return 9?

Tags: wordpress

```
global $post; 
$cat1=get_cat_ID('test1'); 
$cat2=get_cat_ID('test2'); 
$myrecentposts = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat1,-$cat2",'showposts' => 5));
$myrecentposts2 = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat1,-$cat2"));
$myrecentpostscount = count($myrecentposts2);
echo $myrecentpostscount;
```

The value of the echo is 5 (the correct value should be 9). The only way I can get it to return the correct value for the post count is to change the $myrecentposts2  calculation as follows...

```
$myrecentposts2 = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat1,-$cat2",'showposts' => 999));
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Wordpress codex says [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) has a default `posts_per_page` value of `5`.

<del>To remove this limit use `posts_per_page = -1`.</del>

To remove this limit you can use `nopaging = true`.

Comment: its in the wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

btw my bad - its posts_per_page instead of limit :)

Answer (score 11):

Look at the [**`get_posts()`** documentation on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), you can see there's a parameter for number of posts you want to display:

The parameter is: `'posts_per_page'`
 
Usage: `'posts_per_page'=> -1 // for removing the limit`. This will fetch all the posts.

update: `'nopaging' => true` ist the way to go with newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Also, showposts is deprecated as of WP 2.9 (or maybe even 2.8), use posts_per_page whenever you're trying to control the amount of posts returned.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks Gipetto!

What version was posts_per_page introduced? In other words, I don't want to change from showposts if its likely to throw errors on recent wordpress releases...

Comment: Gipetto, when I change from 'showposts' => -1 to 'posts_per_page' => -1, rather than showing all posts, I only get 5. I'm switching back to showposts for now.

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version of WordPress (6.4.3) the correct parameter is:

```
    'numberposts' => -1,
```

according to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/.

Here's a working code snippet of mine for context:

```
/**
 * Calculate and update the video count for all guests based on reverse relationship.
 */
function calculate_video_count_for_single_guest()
{

  // Get the related video IDs using the ACF reverse relationship field
  $related_videos = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'videos', // Replace with your actual video post type
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query' => [
      [
        'key' => 'guest_names', // Replace with the actual ACF field name for reverse relationship
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
      ],
    ],
  ]);

  echo "<pre>" . print_r($related_videos, true) . "</pre>";

}

add_action('admin_notices', 'calculate_video_count_for_single_guest');
```